# Execute animation of subview subclass

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation, uiview

I have a UIViewController called ParentViewController.
And i have a UIView custom class called CustomView. It including some ImageView and the function to execute animation.

CustomView.h

```
@interface CustomView : UIView
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *human;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *shadow;
+ (id)CustomView;
- (void)executeAnimation;
@end
```

And in CustomView.m i ave executeAnimation as the following:

```
-(void)executeAnimation{
    self.animation1InProgress = YES;
    [UIView animateKeyframesWithDuration:3.0 delay:0.0 options:UIViewAnimationCurveLinear animations:^{
        self.human.frame = CGRectMake(self.human.frame.origin.x, self.human.frame.origin.y + 300, self.human.frame.size.width, self.human.frame.size.height);
    } completion:^(BOOL finished){
        self.animation1InProgress = NO;
    }];
}
```

Now in ParentViewController.m, i add CustomView without any animation

```
//init custom
customView = [CustomView initCustomView];
[self.view addSubview:centerLocationView];
```

This code is OK. I could init and addSubview to ParentViewController.
But whenever i would like to execute animation about CustomView. I call the following coding in ParentViewController.m:

```
[customView executeAnimation];
```

There is nothing changed at Parent View.
Is anybody know the way to execute this animation at ParentViewController?

Thank in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really want to use `+[UIView animateKeyframesWithDuration:delay:options:animations:completion:]`, you should add keyframes to your `animations` block:

```
-(void)executeAnimation{
    self.animation1InProgress = YES;
    [UIView animateKeyframesWithDuration:3.0 delay:0.0 options:UIViewAnimationCurveLinear animations:^{
        [UIView addKeyframeWithRelativeStartTime:0.0 relativeDuration:1.0 animations:^{
            self.human.frame = CGRectMake(self.human.frame.origin.x, self.human.frame.origin.y + 300, self.human.frame.size.width, self.human.frame.size.height);
        }];
    } completion:^(BOOL finished){
        self.animation1InProgress = NO;
    }];
}
```

Otherwise, just use `[UIView animateWithDuration:animations:completion:]`:

```
-(void)executeAnimation{
    self.animation1InProgress = YES;
    [UIView animateWithDuration:3.0 delay:0.0 options:UIViewAnimationCurveLinear animations:^{
        self.human.frame = CGRectMake(self.human.frame.origin.x, self.human.frame.origin.y + 300, self.human.frame.size.width, self.human.frame.size.height);
    } completion:^(BOOL finished){
        self.animation1InProgress = NO;
    }];
}
```

Comment: Thanks for quick response. I tried and ParentView could see the animation executed. Thank you very much. However, could you please explain for me about addKeyframeWithRelativeStartTime and relativeDuration ?

Comment: Also, in this case, after execute animation completed. human.frame is reseted to the original position. It should be self.human.frame.origin.y + 300. But now it not

Comment: When you update animatable properties inside `animations` block, you actually update animation layer, not the presentation layer. You will need to set `self.human.frame` to right value once more, but not inside `animations` block. Check this article for details: [Animations Explained](http://www.objc.io/issue-12/animations-explained.html)